# Differential expression gene analysis: how to do t.test on expression matrix with goups different clinical matrix?

Tags: r

I am beginning my PhD in transcriptome (affymetrix assay) analysis.

I have an expression matrix (trans_data : 32000 genes x 620 samples), and a clinical matrix (clin_data : 620 samples x 42 clinical caracteristics). 
The samples belong to 1 of the 4 populations A-B-C-D. I'd like to draw comparision of gene expression between population A and B without triying to bind the two matrix.

I'd like to optain a matrix with mean expression of each genes in the two population, then pvalue, then adjusted p value.

Then I could select only differentially expressed genes (padj < 0,05).

thanks for your help.
Alain

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer your question directly without a [clear reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) but you might want to check out the rather excellent [tableone package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableone/vignettes/introduction.html)